# To match if - else if - else ladder

Tags: regex

An `if`-`else if`-`else` statement may consists of either:

- `if` → `else`
- `if` → `else if` (it could be more than 1 `else if` here)
- `if` → `else if` (it could be more than 1 `else if` here) → `else`
- It cannot consists of `if` → `if`. It will be 2 statements, not 1.

How to to write a regex that will match the first 3 options, but will not match `if`-`if` or simply `if`?

```
// Successfully matches the first 3 options, but *also* matches the single "if". Bad.
If( → Else If)?( → Else)?
```

Comment: What does that mean, "it matches the 4th one"? It should produce two separate matches on that, depending on what regex engine you run it on and with what flags…

Comment: @deceze Sorry, I mean it will match a single `if`. I will edit the question now.

Comment: So it should only match if the entire string consists of exactly *one* `if` ladder, and shouldn't match at all if it contains two? Then you want to add `^` and `$` anchors…

Comment: something like `if → else (if → else)?` seems like it should work for you

Comment: @deceze It should match `if`-`else`, `if`-`else if`, and `if`-`else if`-`else`. It shouldn't match just `if` or `if`-`if`. Hence, simply adding `^` and `$` doesn't help.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, seems to work for me: `if → else( if → else)?( if)?`

Comment: Are you sure you need that last group? It lets it match `if → else if → else if` which wasn't in your description of the problem.

Comment: Thanks to pointing it out. Yes, it should match any number of `else if`. To make it match any number of them, I changed it to `if → else( if → else)+( if)?`, but now it doesn't match `if → else if`. Arghh...

Comment: If my answer solves your problem it'd be nice if you could update your question so that it matches the answer (the "multiple else ifs" part is missing from the description)

Comment: @johnc.j. Thanks mate, glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your regex flavour supports lookarounds, you can use the following :

```
if(?!$)( → else if)*( → else)?
```

That is "if", followed by any number of "else if", then an optional "else". Since those last two parts can be matched 0 times, we use a negative lookahead to make sure we don't match "if"s alone.

You can [try it here](https://regex101.com/r/lAZQe9/4).